# Measuring third party software speed\execution time

Tags: java, windows, performance, time

I've written a function which executes an algorithm. I have done 4 different types and have no problem comparing their execution times(in java). However, there are three existing third party implementations I would like to compare my algorithms against. Of course, as they are closed source, this is not completely possible. However my application has a gui with a button to display the command, followed by a pop-up with the results. ( Despite these not being part of the algorithm, for my purposes, comparing the time it took from clicking execute\run to the time the results are displayed on the screen will suffice.)

I was just wondering about the best practice for comparing the speed of these different methods. I have to do something, so if I cant think of anything i suppose a stopwatch is what I will use, however, a more sophisticated approach would obviously be more desirable.

Comment: More sophisticated from `endTime-startTime`?I don't think there is one

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- i can use it for my functionality but not when comparing with the  third party's, as i do not have access to their source code and can't call any of their functionality from my code. I will simply be testing the third party as an end user.

Comment: Can't you decompile the library and use reflection to call the methods of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can log the time of calling the third party method and dispplay the difference of current time from that logged time. This will give you almost exact timing.

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` like below:

```
long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
//Call the thrd prty method
syso("Time taken:"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, i do not have access to the methods. I will simply have to use the third party application for testing it, as an end-user.

Comment: The stopwatch way seems somehow crude though- i was thinking windows might have some way of timing when new windows pop-up even from within third party applications.